# python: Gnuplot - variable parameter in 'set key' (for example)

Tags: python, variables, gnuplot

I want to:

```
for datafile in glob.glob('*.dat' )
    d = Gnuplot.File(datafile, using='1:2', with_='l', title=datafile)
    g("set key at xpos, [y variable position])
    g.plot(d)
```

The [y variable position] is some simple function, say, y = #graph * (some number).

How (in any way -- I don't give a holler about the most elegant solution) would one do this?

Halp! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(debug=1)
#xpos is always the same
xpos=0.0
for plotnr,datafile in enumerate(glob.glob('*.dat')):
    #ypos as a function of the plot-number, e.g.
    ypos=plotnr*2.0
    g("set key at "+str(xpos)+","+str(ypos))
    d = Gnuplot.File(datafile, using='1:2', with_='l', title=datafile)
    g.plot(d)
```

Comment: Thanks to Raphael. Incidentally, my file names are in the form: 01-xxx.dat, so I use: `files = glob.glob('*svb*.dat' ); files.sort()` to order them.